# C# - ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ms-access

am new to C#.
Please assist!

I keep having the following error: "ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."
I am not able to insert into my database as well.

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace AzureSecureStore
{
    public partial class Client : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection vcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\SB18\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AzureSecureStore\AzureSecureStore\AzcureSecureStore Database.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;");
        //OleDbConnection vcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\SB18\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AzureSecureStore\AzureSecureStore\AzcureSecureStore Database.accdb");
        public Client()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Client_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'azcureSecureStore_DatabaseDataSet5.Client' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.clientTableAdapter.Fill(this.azcureSecureStore_DatabaseDataSet5.Client);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'azcureSecureStore_DatabaseDataSet2.Client' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            //this.clientTableAdapter.Fill(this.azcureSecureStore_DatabaseDataSet2.Client);

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ab = string.Format("insert into Client values({0}, '{1}', '{2}', {3}, {4}, '{5}')",
    textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, int.Parse(textBox3.Text), int.Parse(textBox4.Text), textBox9.Text, int.Parse(textBox10.Text));
            OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(ab, vcon);
            vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data stored successfully");
            vcom.Dispose();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

you forgot to open the connection,

```
vcon.Open();
vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but remember to use

- `using` statement -- to properly dispose objects
- `try-catch` block -- to properly catch exceptions (*exception handling*)

**UPDATE 1**

```
string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\SB18\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AzureSecureStore\AzureSecureStore\AzcureSecureStore Database.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
string query = "INSERT INTO Client VALUES(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6)";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = query;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", textBox1.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", textBox2.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col3", int.Parse(textBox3.Text));
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col4", int.Parse(textBox4.Text));
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col5", textBox9.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col6", int.Parse(textBox10.Text));
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data stored successfully");
        }
        catch(OleDbException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

- [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)
- [Add (*recommended to use*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx)

Comment: Hi, i did what you mentioned but i get the following error: "OleDbException was unhandled." No value given for one or more parameters.What should i do?

Comment: Um, i did the changes. But the data still won't get into my database. Not exactly an error but i get the following popup when i click insert: "Systems.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs"

Comment: the code can run on its own. try putting it in a method an call that method.

Comment: @user1971823 - sounds like you've got the wrong variable having `ToString()` called on it in the `catch` clause - it should be the reference to the exception two lines above. You probably had to change that reference since the sample in this answer uses `e`, but `e` is the second argument to your function.

Answer (score 2):

For connect with database you need to open connection
so use

```
vcon.Open();
```

and then

```
vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Hi, i did what you mentioned but i get the following error: "OleDbException was unhandled." No value given for one or more parameters.What should i do?